# How to handle multiple dynamically created tables with soring in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have multiple dynamically created Angular tables, each displaying the same columns but with different data.  I need to sort the columns in each table separately.  I currently have two tables.  When I click on the column header arrow on the first one, it sorts correctly.  Clicking on the same column in the second table does nothing.

Here is the relevant html:

```
  <div appMaterialElevation *ngFor="let item of tables; let i = index">  
    <table
      mat-table
      [dataSource]="item.dataSource"
      multiTemplateDataRows
      matSort
      matSortActive="configName"
      matSortDirection="asc"
    > 
      <ng-container matColumnDef="configName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Table Name</th>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Here is the relevant TS:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewChildren, QueryList, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
export class Row {
  configName: string;
}

export class FormatData {
  formatName: string;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Row>;
  selection: SelectionModel<Row>;
}

export class ConfigureFormatsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChildren(MatPaginator) paginators = new QueryList<MatPaginator>();
  @ViewChildren(MatSort) sorts = new QueryList<MatSort>();
  tables: FormatData[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['configName'];

  getconfigformats() {
    this.tables = [] as FormatData[];    
    this.myService.getMyData()
      .subscribe((configList: MyConfigs[]) => {
        let table = new FormatData();
        let configNamesList = [] as Row[];
        configList.forEach(config => {
          let row = new Row();
          row.configName = config.configName;
          configNamesList.push(row);
         });
       table.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Row>(configNamesList);
       table.selection = new SelectionModel<Row>(true, []);
       this.tables.push(table);
       this.ngAfterViewInit();
     }
   });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    for (let i=0; i<this.tables.length; i++) {
      let table = this.tables[i];
      table.dataSource.sort = this.sorts.toArray()[i];
      table.dataSource.paginator = this.paginators.toArray()[i];
    };
  }
```

Can anybody see my mistake?

Comment: Maybe try creating a child component for the table and pass in the datasource? You would then ensure there is one and only one MatSort per table and not need to loop through a QueryList

Comment: you would be best of seperating the table into its own component and have an @input on it to set the datasource, that way you encapsulate table functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need assing the sort to each "dataSource"

So,I imagine you want to make some like

```
this.tables.forEach((item,i)=>{
  item.dataSource.sort=this.sort.find((_,index)=>index==i)
}
```

See how we select the QueryList using `find((_x,index)`

IMPORTANT NOTE: is

```
   //see that is without ()
  @ViewChildren(MatPaginator) paginators = new QueryList<MatPaginator>;
  @ViewChildren(MatSort) sorts = new QueryList<MatSort>;
```

**Update** it's necesary "give time to Angular" to draw the tables. we can make enclosing into a setTimeout when assign the matsort.

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-eoxamm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I use some like

```
  dataSources:MatTableDataSource<any>[]=[]
  @ViewChildren(MatSort) sorts:QueryList<MatSort>

  ngOnInit()
  {
    service.getData().subscribe((res:any[])=>{
      res.forEach((x,index)=>{
           this.dataSources[index]=new MatTableDataSource(x)
       })
       setTimeout(()=>{
        this.dataSources.forEach((x,index)=>{
          x.sort=this.sorts.find((_,i)=>i==index)
        })
       })
      })
  }
```

**Update2** I don't know about your code, so you can create a function

```
setSorts()
{
   setTimeout(()=>{
      this.tables.forEach((item:any,index:number)=>{
        const sort=this.sorts.find((_,i:number)=>i==index)
        item.dataSource.sort=sort
      })
   })
}
```

NOTE: **important** your dataSource should be a MatTableDataSource, that's. If you has an array you should write

```
table.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource<Row>(yourArray);
```

It's necesary the setTimeout because, when you add an element to your array still you have no sort. You need "wait" Angular paint the tables. the setTimeout say to Angular: "eh! paint the tables and, after you've painted execute the functions under the setTimeout.

And call always you add/remove one element to the array "this.tables" (each time you make a this.tables.push(..) or this.tables.remove)

About the use of find((_x,index)=>....), an array or a queryList has methods: forEach,map,find.. that generally we use with an unique "argument", e.g. `

```
myArray.forEach((x:any)=>{...x is the value of the element..}
```

But all this methods allow a second argument that is the index of the element, e.g.

```
myArray.forEach((x:any,index:number)=>{
 ...x is the value of the element and index the position..
 console.log(x,index)
}
```

When you use with "find" you can get the element in the position "index", as we needn't the value of the variable, I usually use a `_` (but you can use any name of the variable

Comment: new always needs ().  Anyway this didn't work either.  Got error about ngOnDestroy is missing in type 'ConfigurationFormatsComponent' but required in type 'OnDestroy' even though it is defined: ngOnDestory(){}

Comment: sorry, I don't see that you're trying create a QueryList. Really should be `@ViewChildren(MatPaginator) paginators!:QueryList<MatPaginator>;` -the "!" is to say Angular that you yet know that can be undefined" (If I have time try to create a stackblitz

Comment: @user3217883, I update the answer adding a stackblitz

Comment: Thanks for the stackblitz example.  That is great!  I'm trying to integrate your example into my code.  In my code it takes three different database calls to finally get all the data for the tables, which are stored in the "tables" variable.

Comment: see that when you *after** create the tables, should enclosed under setTimeout() to assign the sort (until tables has no value, Angular not "paint" the tables. so you need give time to paint(*). Really you not give time, the setTimeout say to Angular "paint the tables and when you finished, remember that you should make the instructions under setTimeout"

Comment: I add a datasource and a datasource.sort to each of tables, but it doesn't work.   Can you explain the sorts.find command in your example?  I don't understand the syntax. 
          x.sort=this.sorts.find((_,i)=>i==index)
I'll try putting it in a setTimeout and see it that works

Comment: In your example, you have three tables.  Quantity of tables is known.  My code has variable number of tables, stored in "tables" array.

Comment: I accepted your answer even though I can't get it to work with my code.  I have     setTimeout(()=>{
      this.tables.forEach((x,index)=>{
        x.dataSource.sort=this.sorts.find((_,i)=>i==index)
      })
    }); but it says  "',' expected" at the last }.  Formatting looks right to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242739/discussion-between-eliseo-and-user3217883).